# "Unknown property" when extending DateInterval

Tags: php, oop

This does work:

```
$test = new Test();
$test->blah();

class Test // extends DateInterval
{
    private $foo = 0;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function blah()
    {
        echo $this->foo;
        echo $this->bar;
    }

    public function __get($n) { echo $n; }
}
```

The output is, as expected, `0bar`.

But as soon as I uncomment the `extends DateInterval` part, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Test::blah(): Unknown property (foo)

This happens with PHP 5.3.2 on Linux and it does not happen with PHP 5.3.8 on Windows.

Comment: May be you get error
Fatal error: Test::blah(): Unknown property (bar) ?

Comment: No, I don't because the fatal error stops execution before it gets to that line.

Comment: @AndreKR The code you posted works fine. Are you sure you have posted all relevant parts?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole code of my test case. Did you uncomment the `extends`? And did you try it in PHP 5.3.2 on Linux?

Comment: @AndreKR I tried it again on an older linux version and was able to reproduce the behaviour. A quick google search revealed more (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug that got fixed in version 5.3.6 according to [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52738) and [this](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) page.

`Fixed bug #52738 (Can't use new properties in class extended from DateInterval). (Stas)`

Seems your only option is to switch to another PHP version.